# Deserialising a json text file without json.net

Tags: c#, json

I have some json data stored in a text file (the data is at https://github.com/VinceG/Auto-Cars-Makes-And-Models). I've run the json file through json2csharp which has generated the following classes for storage

```
public class Model
{
    public string value { get; set; }

    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleMake
{
    public string value { get; set; }

    public string title { get; set; }

    public List<Model> models { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to deserialise the data into the VehicleMake class using the following code

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Let's deserialise!");
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader("models.json"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
        var vehicleList = Deserialize<VehicleMake>(sb.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    private static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
    {
        T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        try
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
                obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
                ms.Close();
                return obj;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception throw in Deserialize - {0}-{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

I've used this deserialize method in a number of different project and it has never caused an issue. Here though it is returning null into the `vehicleList` object.

The string builder.ToString() looks to contain all of the data (it is showing Other Yugo Models for the the final title which is correct)

I'm deliberately not using json.net as it's the only deserialisation of json I'm doing within this application and so it's somewhat overkill.

I should say that this isn't a homework project or anything like that

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, the target platform doesn't have access to the JavascriptSerialiser class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json string represents an array, so you need to deserialize it to a `List<VehicleMake>`. Just change the following line:

```
var vehicleList = Deserialize<VehicleMake>(sb.ToString());
```

with:

```
var vehicleList = Deserialize<List<VehicleMake>>(sb.ToString());
```

You'll get a list of vehicles with properly initialized value, title and models properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes to your class and members. Possibly also [Serializable]

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Model
{
    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public string value { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "title")]    
    public string title { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class VehicleMake
{
    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public string value { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "title")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "models")]
    public List<Model> models { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - it's still returning null for all values in vehicleList though

Comment: I feel stupid for not noticing that you were casting to a single VehicleMake now :)